# Im getting this error: Error executing script RunApp: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, groovy

My environment variable are fine, I'm using `grails 2.3.7` with `jdk 1.7`
It just don't compile. I already tried to reinstall `java`, my IDE, tried to run on cmd, tried the command

```
grails -clean
```

Getting this error

> Error executing script RunApp:
>   org/codehaus/groovy/grails/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler

All didn't work. Any solutions??

Comment: The title does not say much about the problem. Is there any more output available? Can you build from command line?

Comment: Check this thread http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-resolve-class-org-codehaus-groovy-grails-compiler-GrailsProjectCompiler-td4641043.html